# Digitization tool not showing split in QGIS

Tags: qgis, splitting

I have a line shapefile and a polygon shapefile (boundary+map). I want to split the polygon with the line (making my map have two distinct areas) . I used the digitization tool and no errors appear but the polygon is not split. I have already successfully done this with a different line file. Suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain how you are trying to do this. Also a screenshot could help.

Comment: i have selected the polygon with toggle editing as well as the line file. i have then selected the "split feature with line" tool from digitization toolbar. I did the same process on the same polygon but with a different line and it worked fine. I dont get an error message. after i select the split tool, it would appear that nothing went wrong - but also, nothing happens...

Comment: Does the line cross the polygon? Also, are they in the same CRS?

Comment: Something else to consider: do your input shapefiles contain any topology and/or geometry errors? Shapefiles are particularly prone to such problems, and they can appear out of nowhere.  I don't have QGIS available at the moment, but I recall one or more tools to check and repair this, either in the default install Vector dropdown menu, or as a plugin tool.